# Getting warning and not able to open my react project when i use proxy?

Tags: reactjs, api, express, axios, proxy

//pakage.json
//This is package.json file where i user proxy
is this a good way for the api calls?

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api/"
}
```

//terminal
//Here my terminal and getting warning

```
PS F:\MERN\netflix-clone\netflix> npm start

> netflix@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

When "proxy" is specified in package.json it must start with either http:// or https://
PS F:\MERN\netflix-clone\netflix>
```

//can anyone add a short documentation on proxy`

> enter code here

`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question. it will help you to get quick responses

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem might be the `/api/` at the end of the proxy.
Try removing the `/api/`:
`"proxy": "http://localhost:8800"`